# Why must I free this data? Am I the owner?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, core-graphics

This is strange. In a [technical Q & A](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1509/_index.html), Apple says this:

```
void *data = CGBitmapContextGetData (cgctx);
if (data != NULL)
{

    // **** You have a pointer to the image data ****

    // **** Do stuff with the data here ****

}

// When finished, release the context
CGContextRelease(cgctx); 
// Free image data memory for the context
if (data)
{
    free(data);
}
```

I looked up the documentation for CGBitmapContextGetData, and it does not mention that I am responsible for releasing the data when I call this. There is already the CGContextRelease call which cleans up the context.

What is the point of having to extra-release the data inside the context? It is just a pointer to that data, right? Why do they call `free(data)` here?

Comment: Interpreting this with knowledge of the Create and Get rules of the Core Foundation Memory Management Guide would lead directly to the conclusion that you do NOT, in fact, own that void pointer. So good question, I would not have thought to free it.

Comment: @Matt Wilding: And you're correct: Getting that pointer does not mean you need to free it. If Quartz allocated it for you when you created the context, Quartz will be responsible for freeing it. If you allocated it and provided it for the context to use, you remain responsible for freeing it. The `CGBitmapContextGetData` call does not change anything either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: I neglected to read the entire code example. Apple allocates `bitmapData` in `CreateARGBBitmapContext()` but does not free it. Which is perfectly fine, since the context still needs to do draw into it.

However, `bitmapData` will have to later be released when they're done with the drawing, which is exactly what they do at the end of `ManipulateImagePixelData()`. So while it is unusual to release something that was obtained by a get function, it **the sample code is correct**.

To avoid the confusion of freeing something that was returned from a get function, one might want to store the bitmap data in a global / instance variable and `free()` that when done.

---

I would assume this to be a bug in the code example. The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGBitmapContextGetData) of this function does not mention anything special, so there's no reason why the [Get Rule](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html) would not apply here. The [Quartz 2D Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_overview/dq_overview.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH202-TPXREF101) also specifically reiterates that the CoreFoundation memory management model applies to the Quartz 2D API.

Answer (score 1):

I'm 100% unfamiliar with coding anything Apple related, but I'd imagine that the cgctx has nothing to do with the data pointer, so you would have to free it on its own.  I.E. The CGContextRelease() doesn't clean up the pointer.

Comment: so free is something different than release? What does free do anyways? From what I know it is the opposite of malloc. But I don't do any malloc.

Comment: `free()` and `release` are quite different. The `free()` function instantly frees the memory, no questions asked. The `release` method in Objective-C (and the `CFRelease` function) only decrement the reference count of the object by one. Only once the reference count reaches zero, the object is `dealloc`ed and its memory `free()`d.

Comment: So shouldn't we better release() the bitmap data object then, instead of free()?

Comment: @Mikhalo Ivanokov: No, because you can't do that. `release` is a message; you can only send a message to a Cocoa or CF object. The buffer `malloc` allocates for you is not a Cocoa or CF object; it is simply an array of bytes, nothing more, with nothing to reference-count it (so you cannot retain or release it by any means). The counterpart to `malloc` is `free`; that is what you must use to destroy the buffer.