# How to correctly clean up the memory when creating a CGContextRef?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, core-graphics

When I create a CGContextRef manually using `CGBitmapContextCreate()`, do I have to manually free the bitmap data as well?

Right now I'm doing this: I have a method that creates and returns a CGContextRef. Inside that method, I also create the data for that context, like this:

```
bitmapData = malloc(bitmapByteCount);
context = CGBitmapContextCreate(bitmapData, ...);
return context;
```

Until now I always believed that everything is just fine when the caller of this method simply releases the CGContextRef after using it: `CGContextRelease(theContext);`

From the documentation of `CGBitmapContextCreate`:

> In iOS 4.0 and later, and Mac OS X
>   v10.6 and later, you can pass NULL if
>   you want Quartz to allocate memory for
>   the bitmap. This frees you from
>   managing your own memory, which
>   reduces memory leak issues.

This makes me think I do have to release two things after using my context which a convenience method created for me: Release the bitmap data of the context, and then the context itself.

So I must do this:

```
void *data = CGBitmapContextGetData(context);
if (data != NULL) {
    free(data);
}
```

So am I having a big memory leak here if I don't refactor all my code to release also the bitmap data, and not only the context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You do have to eventually `free()` bitmapData (once the CGContext is done drawing etc.) if you `malloc()`ed it.

See my (corrected) answer to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391482/why-must-i-free-this-data-am-i-the-owner).

If you use the NULL option (i.e. if you do **not** `malloc()` your bitmapData), I would expect the data pointer to be valid until you `CGContextRelease()` your context. So you'd either need to do whatever you want to do with the data before releasing the context, or copy the bitmap data somewhere (in which case you could just as well `malloc()` the memory beforehand and pass it to the context).